# Can I upgrade to business on one leg only?

Tags: upgrades, ana, business-class

I have booked the CHEAPEST economy (the most restrictive) ticket from Manila to NY on ANA with a stopover in Tokyo. However, I want to try business class only on one leg (as the whole trip in business is expensive) , preferably the Tokyo to New York flight. How can I upgrade to business (includes paying the difference) on only one leg? If I can, how much will it be?

Comment: Talk to the airline. I'm sure they'd welcome an opportunity to take more money from you. They'd also be the only people who could tell you the cost.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade at all? On some airlines, the cheapest tickets can't be upgraded.

Comment: @Jake I’d ask to upgrade on the final leg if you can. It’d be pretty terrible having to go back to Economy after experiencing Business class :-)

Comment: I called ANA airlines and they said it is possible to upgrade one leg to business class.